# Software updater and Ubuntu Software apps are not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates, software-center, update-manager

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uo7p.png) is what I see whenever I open Ubuntu Software app and for the software updater app it constantly gives me `Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection` error.

Comment: With me, it doesn't open at all, when you click it the mouse just spins and quiet without anything opening.

Comment: @MercyFlicker I also had the same problem but then I installed the older version `Ubuntu Software Center` and after that the newer one started opening but won't load anything.